# xcode unrecognized selector sent to instance error

Tags: xcode

I am new to xcode iOS programming and I really need your help with the error of unrecognised selector sent to instance. Below is my implementation

```
//.h file
@interface AppAccountController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>{

   IBOutlet UITextField *txtName;
   IBOutlet UITextField *txtEmail;
   IBOutlet UIDatePicker *dateOB;
   IBOutlet UITextField *txtPwd;
   IBOutlet UITextField *txtRePwd;
}

- (IBAction)btnSave:(id)sender;
@end


//.m file

@interface AppAccountController ()

 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtName;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtEmail;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *dateOB;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtPwd;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtRePwd;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnSave;

@end

@implementation AppAccountController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)btnSave:(id)sender {

// Create strings to store the text info
NSString *name = [txtName text];
NSString *email  = [txtEmail text];
NSDate *dob = [dateOB date];
NSString *passwd = [txtPwd text];
NSString *repasswd = [txtRePwd text];

if ([txtName.text isEqualToString:@""])
{
    [txtName becomeFirstResponder];
    UIAlertView* finalCheck = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Attention"
                               message:@"Name Field is empty. Please enter a name"
                               delegate:self
                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                               otherButtonTitles:nil] ;

    [finalCheck show];
    finalCheck.tag = 1;
}
else if ([txtEmail.text isEqualToString:@""])
{
    [txtEmail becomeFirstResponder];
    UIAlertView* finalCheck = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Attention"
                               message:@"Email Field is empty. Please enter an Email"
                               delegate:self
                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                               otherButtonTitles:nil] ;
    [finalCheck show];
    finalCheck.tag = 2;
}
else if ([txtPwd.text isEqualToString:@""])
{
    [txtPwd becomeFirstResponder];
    UIAlertView* finalCheck = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Attention"
                               message:@"Password Field is empty. Please enter a Password"
                               delegate:self
                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                               otherButtonTitles:nil] ;
    [finalCheck show];
    finalCheck.tag = 3;
}
else if ([txtRePwd.text isEqualToString:@""])
{
    [txtRePwd becomeFirstResponder];
    UIAlertView* finalCheck = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Attention"
                               message:@"Confirm Password Field is empty. Please enter to confirm Password"
                               delegate:self
                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                               otherButtonTitles:nil] ;
    [finalCheck show];
    finalCheck.tag = 4;
}
else if (![passwd isEqualToString:repasswd])
{
    [txtPwd becomeFirstResponder];
    UIAlertView* finalCheck = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Attention"
                               message:@"Passwords do not match. Please enter to confirm Password"
                               delegate:self
                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                               otherButtonTitles:nil] ;
    [finalCheck show];
    finalCheck.tag = 5;
}
else{
    // Store the data
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [defaults setObject:name forKey:@"name"];
    [defaults setObject:email forKey:@"email"];
    [defaults setObject:passwd forKey:@"passwd"];
    [defaults setObject:dob forKey:@"dob"];


    [defaults synchronize];

    NSLog(@"Data saved");
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"saveLoad" sender:self];
 }    
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
if(alertView.tag == 1) {
    [txtName becomeFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"Name AlertView is clicked");
}
else if(alertView.tag == 2) {
    [txtEmail becomeFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"Email AlertView is clicked");
}
else if(alertView.tag == 3) {
    [txtPwd becomeFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"Password AlertView is clicked");
}
else if(alertView.tag == 4) {
    [txtRePwd becomeFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"Re-Password AlertView is clicked");
}
else if(alertView.tag == 5) {
    [txtRePwd becomeFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"Re-Password AlertView is clicked");
}
}
@end
```

Whenever I press the btnSave button or after moving on to another UI element (one element gaining focus after another one losses it), I get unrecognised selector sent to instance.

UPDATE

```
2014-12-18 18:06:23.794 XPB[964:35743] -[AppAccountController btnSave:forEvent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd949d923f0
2014-12-18 18:06:23.834 XPB[964:35743] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppAccountController btnSave:forEvent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd949d923f0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bd2df35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010a182bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bd3504d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bc8d27c ___forwarding___ + 988
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bc8ce18 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x00000001087e98be -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
    6   UIKit                               0x00000001088f0410 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001088ef7df -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010882f308 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 735
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010882fc33 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 683
    10  UIKit                               0x00000001087fc9b1 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000108809a7d _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 17370
    12  UIKit                               0x00000001087e5103 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1961
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bc63551 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bc5941d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bc58a54 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bc58486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010c64e9f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
    18  UIKit                               0x00000001087e8420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    19  XPB                                 0x00000001083965b3 main + 115
    20  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010ce4b145 start + 1
    21  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Show us the entire message!  It's actually got useful information in it!!

Comment: `[AppAccountController btnSave:forEvent:]` -- You apparently didn't implement btnSave correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `btnSave:` and `btnSave:forEvent:` are two different things.

Your AppAccountController has a `btnSave:` method, so it can be sent the `btnSave:` message. But it has no `btnSave:forEvent:` method. Unfortunately, that's the selector you specified to be used whenever the button is pressed. The button is trying to send `btnSave:forEvent:` to your AppAccountController, and AppAccountController doesn't know what to do with that. So it crashes.

The easiest solution is to fix the button so that it sends `btnSave:` and not `btnSave:forEvent:`. (You will almost never need the two-parameter variant of an action method in any case.)

Comment: Interesting, never heard of an action/target where you also send the event as an argument (in addition to the typical `sender`). The closest thing I've seen is e.g. `-tocuhesBegan:withEvent:` etc. I wonder how you set that up with Interface Builder.

Comment: "never heard of an action/target where you also send the event" Well, @NicolasMiari, you are very young, and the world is full of wonders. See the discussion in my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch11.html#_actions The two-parameter form is in fact the full form; there is a one-parameter form and a zero-parameter form.

Comment: @NicolasMiari Next time you control-drag from a button to your code, look carefully at the pop-up when you form the Action: it actually asks you whether you want zero, one, or two parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I was aware of the zero or one parameter popup; I must have missed the two-parameter entry somehow...

Comment: @NicolasMiari As I explain in my book, the second parameter is almost never needed. But you might want, say, the `timestamp` from the UIEvent.

Comment: Also, I remember reading somewhere that it was more common/customary to use the zero-parameters form many years ago, but recently the one-parameter version is recommended (by Apple? not sure...).

Comment: @Matt, thanks for your help but I don't really know how to implement what you are talking about. I am new to object-C and would welcome an example.